# Accessing filtersource in MVC Razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

How do I implement what's in the `change:function(e)` in MVC Razor shown below?  I have been pounding my head against this for days and cannot find anything.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var items = [
    {value : '1',
     desc : 'fred'},
    {value : '2',
     desc : 'wilma'},
    {value : '3',
     desc : 'pebbles'},
    {value : '4',
     desc : 'dino'}
];

var cb = $('#comboBox').kendoComboBox({
    dataSource : items,
    dataTextField : 'desc',
    dataValueField : 'value',
    filter : 'contains',
    change : function (e) {
        if (this.value() && this.selectedIndex == -1) {    
            this._filterSource({
                value: "",
                field: this.options.dataTextField,
                operator: "contains"
            });
            this.select(1);
        }
    }
}).data('kendoComboBox');

$('#showValue').click(function () {
    alert(cb.value());
});

});
```

working example here --> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gVWBf/27/)

---

Here is what I have so far.  What's inside the `if` statement doesn't do anything.

```
function onChange(e) {
    var lT = $("#loadType").data("kendoComboBox").input.val();
    if (lT != "Generic") {
        // Here I need to compare what's entered to what is populated in the comboBox dropdown
        if (this.selectedIndex == -1) {
            this._filterSource({ 
                value: "",
                field: this.options.dataTextField,
                operator: "contains"
            });
            this.select(1);

                //this is for Testing purposes only
                alert("See Me?");
            }

        //this is for Testing purposes only
        alert(lT + " " + this.selectedIndex + " " + this.value());
    }
};
```

For completeness here is the combobox as well:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.loadDescrip, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                    .Name("loadDescrip")
                    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                    .DataTextField("DocCode")
                    .DataValueField("DocCode")
                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("GetCascadeDocumentNumbers", "DockDoor")
                                .Data("filterLoadDescription");
                        })
                      .ServerFiltering(true);
                    })
                    .Enable(false)
                    .AutoBind(false)
                    .CascadeFrom("loadType")
                    .Events(e =>
                        {
                e.Change("onChange");
                        })
            )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.loadDescrip)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? Do you need to convert this to server-wrapper syntax?

Comment: Yes, specifically the Change Event.  I cannot seem to figure out how to implement what's inside it in Server-Wrapper syntax.

Comment: The problem is that your ComboBox has name "loadDescrip" while you try to get it with "loadType".

Comment: nope, "loadType" is a different ComboBox.  They are in a cascading relationship.  I left that out thinking it was not related.  Can include if it'll help.  I just can't get the `_filterSource` and `select(1)` to work.  They don't DO anything seemingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle events in Razor in two ways:

1. Specify the name of the event handler

   ```
   @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
         .Name("combobox")
         .Events(events => events.Change("combobox_change"))
   )
   <script>
   function combobox_change(e) {
     // handle the event
   }
   </script>
   ```
2. Define the event handler as a Razor template delegate

   ```
   @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
     .Name("combobox")
     .Events(events => events.Change(@<text>
         function(e) {
            // handle the event
         }
     </text>))
   )
   ```

More info can be found here: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/combobox/overview#handling-kendo-ui-combobox-events

Comment: Sorry, I see now I wasn't very clear.  I have an event I just can't get the code inside the example event to work in my version.  I will modify the question with my code.  Thanks for the help!